# Get the output ordered by 1, 2, 3 following by elements using loop in array

Tags: arrays, for-loop

I think that this function is very easy, but I am not able to find the way to solve this:

I have an array like this:

```
var results = "";
var example = ['Bank 1', 'Bank 2', 'Bank 3'];
```

I need to use a for loop to print each elements something like this:

```
1 - Bank 1
2 - Bank 2
3 - Bank 3
```

I though to use a for loop as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
  results += "<strong>" + i + "</strong>" + "    -    " + "<strong>"  example[i].toUpperCase() + "</strong>\n\n";
}
```

But the results are:

```
0    -    Bank 1
1    -    Bank 2
2    -    Bank 3
```

I want the output starting from 1 but printing the same way all elements of array:

```
1    -    Bank 1
2    -    Bank 2
3    -    Bank 3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
results += "<strong>" + i + "</strong>" + "    -    " + "<strong>"  example[i].toUpperCase() + "</strong>\n\n";
```

to

```
results += "<strong>" + (i+1) + "</strong>" + "    -    " + "<strong>"  example[i].toUpperCase() + "</strong>\n\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
    results += "<strong>" + (i + 1) + "</strong>" + "    -    " + "<strong>" + example[i].toUpperCase() + "</strong>\n\n";
}
```

Don't forget the missing "+" before example[i].toUpperCase()

Comment: Oh, sure. I forgot it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
    results += "<strong>" + i + "</strong>" + "    -    " + "<strong>"  
    example[i].toUpperCase() + "</strong>\n\n";
}
```

`i` starts at 0. `i++` means that `i` will get incremented, but it will only get incremented **after** each loop iteration. So when you print Bank 1, `i` is 0. Then when you print Bank 2, `i` is 1.

To fix it, you need to print the value of `i+1`:

```
results += "<strong>" + (i+1) + "</strong>" + "    -    " + "<strong>" + example[i].toUpperCase() + "</strong>\n\n";
```